# How to call and render a template by button click listener

Tags: javascript, templates

I have created a template in html and I want to call it by using button click listener. Any idea?
   HTML

```
<template id="tem">
 <p>hi </p>
 </template>
```

Comment: I already know how to create a button and listener this is just to simplify the question :) @PatrickHund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const templateElement = document.getElementById("tem");
const templateCopy = document.importNode(templateElement.content, true);
// insert
document.body.appendChild(templateCopy);
```